# How to add additional claims to Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 3 application

Tags: blazor-client-side

I created a Asp.Net Core hosted Blazor webassembly 3.2.0 Preview 3 application with the authentication option of In-App accounts. I then added a few additional attributes to the ApplicationUser class, and migrated these changes to the database. I then implemented a custom claims factory like so:

```
public class MyCustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyCustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName ?? string.Empty));
        .....

        return identity;
    }
}
```

and registered the claims factory in the server application like so:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyCustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

However, when I list the claims in a client web app component, I do not see any of the additional claims I added in the custom claims factory. The code I am using to list the claims is:

```
<AuthorizeView>
   <Authorized>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var claim in context.User.Claims)
        {
            <li><span>@claim.Type</span><span>@claim.Value</span></li>
        }
    </ul>
   </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I verified that the claims factory code is being called.  How can I get the additional claims in the client web app?

Edit: I have even tried using ClaimsTransformer (as suggested [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/01/authorization-claims.aspx)) but I still do not see the additional claims

Comment: I face the exact same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I've made a github repo and got this working for Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0. / .NET & EF 5 Preview - Multiple Roles and Additional User Claims

See: https://github.com/JeepNL/Blazor-WASM-Identity-gRPC

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions of dfkeenan on this thread:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20887

and I added a ProfileService on which i added the claims I needed (CompanyName, CompanyID)

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public ProfileService()
    {
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var nameClaim = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Name);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(nameClaim);

        var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.FindAll("CompanyName"));
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.FindAll("CompanyId"));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and then registered

`services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();`

on ConfigureServices